# R: Sorting vectors by mean in decreasing order while printing the vector names

Tags: r, sorting, vector, mean, names

This is a very basic question. For an assignment, I need to compare the volumes of two bottle-filling machines. Essentially, I want to know which of the two machines fills to a greater volume, so I'm comparing two means based on 10 observations for each machine.

```
machine1 <- c(151.2,150.5,149.2,147.5,152.9,152.0,151.3,149.7,149.4,150.7)
machine2 <- c(151.9,151.4,150.3,151.2,151.0,150.2,151.2,151.4,150.4,151.7)
means <- c(mean(machine1), mean(machine2))
sort(means, decreasing=T) [1]
```

As you'd expect, the output of this is the greatest vector mean, which happens to be the mean of `machine2`:

```
[1] 151.07
```

I'd like the output to be the name of the vector (i.e. `machine2`). If I have a large number of vectors, I want to simply know the name of the vector with the greatest mean, without having to print each vector mean individually and comparing them myself. I've tried using the `names()` command but can't figure out how to integrate it here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can get the objects in a `list` and then use `which.max`

```
names(which.max(sapply(mget(ls(pattern = 'machine\\d+')), mean)))
#[1] "machine2"
```

The `ls` returns all the objects in the global environment as a string with the `pattern` specified  i.e. 'machine' followed by one or more digits (`\\d+`), `mget` gets the value of the objects in a `list`, loop through the `list` with `sapply`, get the `mean` as a `vector` which also have the names as the object name.  The `which.max` gets the index of the maximum mean and wrapping with `names` returns the name of the index